# Port 443 appears to be closed in Nmap scans even when there's no firewall

Tags: firewall, https

I was trying to diagnose a problem where any HTTPS request to my VPS returns with `ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED`. I'm using Let's Encrypt implemented on NGINX while the web server itself is a Node.js app.

The website is served under a specific subdomain, let's just say it is `mysub.domain.com`.

Here's what an Nmap scan on the `mysub.domain.com` comes up with:

```
443/tcp  open     https?
```

And here's what a similar scan on the public IP address comes up with:

```
443/tcp  closed   https
```

My VPS doesn't have any firewall yet, at least in the host itself. Here's the output of `iptables -S`

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

**UPDATE** Here's the output of `netstat -tlpdn`

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      367/sshd        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7283/nginx -g daemo
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      773/mysqld      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7283/nginx -g daemo
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      367/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      5873/nodejs
```

**UPDATE** Here's the NGINX's `sites-available/default` contents

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name mysub.domain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysub.domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysub.domain.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysub.domain.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

The admin on the facility which houses the VPS tells me that they have opened port 443. Are they missing something? Or is it a mistake on my part?

Comment: Please show output for `netstat -tldpn`

Comment: @AlexanderT I've added that.

Comment: Please show your nginx configuration.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I've added that.

Comment: What is the difference between public IP and `mysub.domain.com`?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen `mysub.domain.com` returns `36.#.#.#` while the public IP given to me is `118.#.#.#`.

Comment: Which one is the correct address for your server?

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, the admin did miss something. The facility implements some weird NAT/IP-forwarder thingy and they forgot to forward traffic in port 443 to my VPS.

Comment: these kind of issues should be thouroughly "debuged" with tcpdump for example. So if you do not see any traffic on the servers when HTTPS requested from outside, you will know that something before your server is blocking traffic.